# PHP - Explicit key in multimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

First of all, sorry for the title, but I didn't know what to put exactly to describe the issue.

Back to the problem, this is what I want to get:

```
{"0":{"dep":"DIR","user":"10000008","seen":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"1":{"dep":"TES","user":"10000008","seen":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}}
```

and this is the actual code I am using (that receives data from an input element as array) example:

```
<input type="text" name="dep[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
```

This is the main code I need to "fix":

```
$user = ($_POST['cc_user']);
$dep =  ($_POST['cc_dep']);

$cc = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['cc_dep']);$i++) {
    $cc = array();
    $cc['user'] = $user[$i];
    $cc['dep'] = $dep[$i];
    $cc['seen'] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $x = strval($i);
    $cc2["$x"] = $cc;

    unset($cc);
}

echo json_encode($cc2);
```

At the moment, this is the result instead of the one I want to get:

```
[{"user":"10000008","dep":"DIR","seen":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"user":"10000001","dep":"admin","seen":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

As you can see, the key of the array is not visible, and I need that for an integration on my website.
I tried to specify the `$i` using:

- `(string)$i`
- `stringval($i)`
- `"$i"`

but I didn't manage to solve the problem. Can someone help, even if it is something really easy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `$_POST` with parenthesis?

Comment: I don't get it, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Why not just `$cc2[] = $cc` at the end of your loop?

Comment: @WillardSolutions, you caught correctly and that's what I asked him that even he has not declared `$cc2` variable and only used in loop. So without declaring variable will not give an effect :)

Comment: @NullPointer Please explain then, how was the OP able to get any result after calling `echo json_encode($cc2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is forcing the JSON to be an object.
Non-associative arrays (with all numerical keys) are displayed in JSON format without the key. In PHP numerical-ish strings will be converted to integers when used as array keys.
You can use additional parameter to make it a JSON object.

```
json_encode($cc2, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

Please take a look at the examples in the docs for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)